# [PM2][WARN] Applications API not running and ..502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, pm2

node.js 
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

already restart reboot but unable to fix the problem 
i face the problem after reboot before that all was working fine

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please consider adding [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we will be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/

i get help from this page and make set up ecosystem.json page and strat the ecosystem.json in a poper way than the problem solve.